# User Control: how to add background image on button in setter/getter

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

In user control designer I know how to add background image.
My image (16x16px) is located in user control. How to add this image in code?
How do I embed the image in user control so that when I bring the control to another project, the image also appears?

```
private Bitmap buttonResetImage = null;// <-- here I want to load my initial image.Then the user can change this image as he wishes;

public Bitmap ButtonResetImage
{
    get { return buttonResetImage; }
    set
    {
        buttonResetImage = value;
        btnReset.BackgroundImage = buttonResetImage;
        btnReset.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
    }
}
```

Well since MDP does not respond I found the trick. I need to initialize this:

```
private Bitmap buttonResetImage = global::SliderControl.Properties.Resources.Reset;
```

If I use only:

```
private Bitmap buttonResetImage = SliderControl.Properties.Resources.Reset;
```

I get this error:

```
Error   CS0117  'SliderControl' does not contain a definition for 'Properties'  SliderControl
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7bmi.png

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem. Specifically what have you tried?

Comment: Assuming you have built a UserControl Project (usually, a Windows Forms Control Library), you can add different kind of Resources to your Project. Then just use `Properties.Resources.ResourceName` to set a compatible Property value to a stored Resource. -- You can set a Property of your UC using the Designer.

Comment: ;) you have to wait.we live in different time zones

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a user control that has any kind of resources like :

- images
- fonts
- audio
- icon

and etc, you can create them in a separate project (called `Windows Forms Control Library`) and add resources in it.
after all, the result(in this case, a dll file) contains all the resources and code base you need.you can use it in any where you want.

Comment: Can you provide a very simple example?

Comment: sure, please take a look at this [article](https://www.mindstick.com/articles/51/creating-and-using-windows-forms-control-library-in-c-sharp-dot-net) . It's a bit old, but I belive it can help you.

Comment: Thanks MDP, but this article does not have an Image as properties. It doesn't help me much.

Comment: It contains basic functionality of creating reusable windows forms components.it's not big deal to add images.it like colors. if you need a real example. I can create a simple on for you in github and send you the link.

Comment: How about if I send you my User Control solution?